# Zod validation errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13, zod

In the following next js 14 typescript  code. I am using react hook form and Zod for validation. The error occur when i display the error message when the form is empty :

```
import React from "react";
import category from "@/components/expenses/category";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { z } from "zod";
const schema: any = z.object({
  productName: z.string().min(3).max(150).nonempty(),
  price: z.number().min(0.01).max(100_000).positive(),
  category: z.enum(category),
});
type expenseFromData = z.infer<typeof schema>;
const AddExpenseForm = () => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<expenseFromData>({ resolver: zodResolver(schema) });

  return (
    <div>
      <form
        className="max-w-sm mx-auto"
        onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => console.log(data))}
      >
        <div className="mb-5">
          <label
            htmlFor="productName"
            className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900"
          >
            Product Name
          </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="productName"
            // name="productName"
            className="shadow-sm bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500 dark:shadow-sm-light"
            placeholder="name@flowbite.com"
            {...register("productName")}
          />

          {errors.productName?.message && <p>{errors.productName.message}</p>}
        </div>
        <div className="mb-5">
          <label
            htmlFor="price"
            className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900"
          >
            price
          </label>
          <input
            type="price"
            id="price"
            className="shadow-sm bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500 dark:shadow-sm-light"
            {...register("price")}
          />
        {errors.price?.message && <p>{errors.price.message}</p>}
        </div>
        <div className="mb-5">
          <label
            htmlFor="repeat-password"
            className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900"
          >
            Categories
          </label>
          <select
            id="category"
            className="shadow-sm bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500 dark:shadow-sm-light"
            {...register("category")}
          >
            <option selected>All categories</option>
            {category.map((curEl) => (
              <option value={curEl} key={curEl}>
                {curEl}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
          {errors.category?.message && <p>{errors.category.message}</p>}
        </div>

        <button
          type="submit"
          className="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800"
        >
          Add Product
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddExpenseForm;
```

I am facing this error:

```
Type 'string | FieldError | Merge<FieldError, FieldErrorsImpl<any>>' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
  Type 'FieldError' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
    Type 'FieldError' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactPortal': children, props, keyts(2322)
index.d.ts(1446, 9): The expected type comes from property 'children' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLParagraphElement>, HTMLParagraphElement>'
```

```
 {errors.category?.message && <p>{errors.category.message}</p>} where i get errors
```

I read Zod's documentation. But there is nothing related to this error.
This error I am facing in next js 14 typescript

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `:any` from your schema. You can check out the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-g2jqqf?file=app%2F_components%2Fform.tsx) for a live demo

```
'use client';
import React from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod';
import { z } from 'zod';

const category = ['1', '2', '3'] as const;

const schema = z.object({
  productName: z.string().min(3).max(150).nonempty(),
  price: z.number().min(0.01).max(100_000).positive(),
  category: z.enum(category),
});
type expenseFromData = z.infer<typeof schema>;
const AddExpenseForm = () => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<expenseFromData>({ resolver: zodResolver(schema) });

  return (
    <div>
      <form
        className="max-w-sm mx-auto"
        onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => console.log(data))}
      >
        <div className="mb-5">
          <label
            htmlFor="productName"
            className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-400"
          >
            Product Name
          </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="productName"
            // name="productName"
            className="shadow-sm bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-400 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500 dark:shadow-sm-light"
            placeholder="name@flowbite.com"
            {...register('productName')}
          />

          {errors.productName?.message && <p>{errors.productName.message}</p>}
        </div>
        <div className="mb-5">
          <label
            htmlFor="price"
            className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-400"
          >
            price
          </label>
          <input
            type="price"
            id="price"
            className="shadow-sm bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-400 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500 dark:shadow-sm-light"
            {...register('price')}
          />
          {errors.price?.message && <p>{errors.price.message}</p>}
        </div>
        <div className="mb-5">
          <label
            htmlFor="repeat-password"
            className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-400"
          >
            Categories
          </label>
          <select
            id="category"
            className="shadow-sm bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-400 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500 dark:shadow-sm-light"
            {...register('category')}
          >
            <option selected>All categories</option>
            {category.map((curEl) => (
              <option value={curEl} key={curEl}>
                {curEl}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
          {errors.category?.message && <p>{errors.category.message}</p>}
        </div>

        <button
          type="submit"
          className="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800"
        >
          Add Product
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddExpenseForm;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).